# How to import custom PowerShell module into the remote session?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting, powershell-3.0

I'm developing a custom PowerShell module, which I'd like to use in context of a remote session to a different computer. The following code (which obviously doesn't work) explains what I'm trying to achieve:

```
import-module .\MyCustomModule.psm1
$session = new-pssession -computerName server01
invoke-command -session $session -scriptblock { 
  <# use function defined in MyCustomModule here #> 
}
```

**The first question is whether it is at all possible to achieve this scenario?** I mean I would only like my custom module to be physically present on my machine, not on remote server.

I have found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830827/powershell-remoting-using-imported-module-cmdlets-in-a-remote-pssession), but I didn't manage it to work - it doesn't allow creating a session from remote machine back to the local one. Probably, I faced with the configuration limitations mentioned somewhere in the comments to that thread... Besides, the author mentioned the performance implications which is critical for my solution...

If that's possible, then how?

The version of PowerShell is currently not a constraint - if the solution is only available in PS 3.0 - I can live with this.

Comment: Duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830827/powershell-remoting-using-imported-module-cmdlets-in-a-remote-pssession ?

Comment: I don't believe this is supported right of the box. You'd have to use a hack like they tried. Can I ask why you can't just install the module on the remote computer? That's the smart solution.

Comment: @DavidBrabant, well, yes, it's quite close. However, I failed to make the solution there work, and I'm referencing that thread explicitly to indicate I tried that option and asking for alternatives :)

Comment: @Graimer, the idea was to use any out of the available machines to perform some deployment scenarios, without anything required to be installed on a remote machine. But if the scenario is not supported, we'll have to live with this...

Comment: Why not place the module in a public location, start your scriptblock with `Import-Module \\fileserver\folders\modulefolder` ? Make sure it's digitally signed or use something like `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process` before importing to bypass warnings?

Comment: Does it really need to be a module?  I'm all for modules but `Invoke-Command -FilePath` will transport a single script file to the remote machine for execution.  Of course, if the script file tries to dot source or otherwise invoke other script files, they have to be on the remote machine because Invoke-Command won't copy them there automatically.

Comment: @KeithHill, hmm, yes... I mean, no... :) You've messed up my PowerShell universe before it started to become mature! It doesn't have to be a module unless we talk about scalability and well-structured, modular and easy-to-reuse code. But I see your point and I will weigh the pros and cons in my particular case. Actually, I'm in process of (first prototyping, then) creating a deployment framework for our application, and splitting the utility functions and cmdlets into modules seemed the way to go to me. How would you approach the task? Is it reliable to require some prerequisites on a target?

Comment: At the risk of messing with your PowerShell universe some more, is there some reason functions cannot be scalable, well-structured, modular, and easy-to reuse without being put into a module?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There were some great comments to the question, and I've spent some time investigating various ways to approach the problem.

To begin with, what I've initially asked for is not possible. I mean, if you go the module way, then the module should be physically present on a target machine to be able to `Import-Module` into remote session.

To abstract my question further, I'm trying to create a reusable PowerShell-based framework for the product deployments. It's going to be a push-manner deployments, meaning that we encourage people to run some scripts on a local machine to deploy to some remote server. As far as I investigated the area, there are two possible ways which are friendly to the common sense.

### Modules approach

The process to follow:

- place each logically different piece of functionality into the PowerShell module (`*.psm1`)
- distribute the module to the remote machine and extend the `PSModulePath` variable to include the new modules location
- on a client machine, create a new session to the remote server, and use `Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {...}`
- in the script block start from `Import-Module CustomModule` - it will search the `CustomModule` on a remote machine and obviously will find it

#### Advantages

The following are the reasons to love this approach for:

- the consequence of the traditional module role - facilitate the creation of reusable libraries
- according to the great book [Windows PowerShell in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182137), "modules can be used to create domain-specific applications". As far as I understand, it can be achieved by combining the module nesting and mixing script / binary modules to expose the intuitive interface specific to a certain domain. Basically, this is the one I value most for the goal of PowerShell-based deployment framework

#### Disadvantages

The following is important to take into consideration:

- You have to find a way to deliver the custom modules to the remote machine. I have played with [NuGet](http://nuget.codeplex.com/), and I'm not sure it suits well for the task, but there are other options as well, for instance, MSI installer or plain `xcopy` from the shared folder. Besides, the delivery mechanism should support upgrade / downgrade and (preferably) multi-instance installations, but that's more related to my task than to the problem in general

### Scripts approach

The process to follow:

- place each logically different piece of functionality in a separate PowerShell script (*.ps1)
- on a client machine, create a new session to the remote server, and use `Invoke-Command -Session $s -FilePath .\myscript.ps1` to load the functions defined in a script to the remote session
- use another `Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {...}` and refer to your custom functions - they will be there in a session

#### Advantages

The following are good points of this approach:

- it is simple - you don't have to know about module peculiarities. Just write plain PowerShell scripts and that's it
- you don't have to deliver anything to the remote machine - this makes the solution even simpler and less error-prone in maintenance

#### Disadvantages

Sure, it's not ideal:

- there's less control over the solution: for instance, if you "import" a set of functions to the session, all of them are "imported" and visible to the user, so no "encapsulation", etc. **I'm sure many solutions can live with this, so don't decide based on this point only**
- the functionality in each file has to be self-contained - any dot-sourcing or module import from there will search the remote machine, not the local one

Finally, I should say that remote machine still needs to be prepared for the remoting. This is what I mean:

- execution policy should be changed to something, because it is restricted by default: `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`
- PowerShell remoting should be enabled: `Enable-PSRemoting`
- the account the script runs as should be added to the local administrators of the remote server
- if you plan to access file shares in the remote session, make sure you are aware about [multi-hop authentication and take proper actions](http://www.ravichaganti.com/blog/?p=1230)
- make sure your antivirus is your friend and doesn't send you to the [PowerShell hell](http://mikefrobbins.com/2012/06/21/welcome-to-powershell-hell/)

Comment: Does anyone know if something has changed in the last 3 years to make this easier?

Comment: it seems like the main disadvantage with Modules Approach: it opens up a redundancy can-of-worms (inconsistent version of a module/script on each target).

Comment: @JustinHelgerson for what it's worth 4 years later, I've [added an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65397310/727345) showing how to do it in PS 5.0 without needing a shared directory, pre-installing modules on remote machines, or recreating a module dynamically.

Answer (score 7):

Here's another approach: Recreate the module in a remote session, without copying any files.

I've made no attempt to cope with dependencies between modules, but this seems to work ok for simple self contained modules. It relies on the module being available in the local session, as this makes determining exports easier, but with a bit of extra work it would also work with a module file.

```
function Import-ModuleRemotely([string] $moduleName,[System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSession] $session)
{
    $localModule = get-module $moduleName;
    if (! $localModule) 
    { 
        write-warning "No local module by that name exists"; 
        return; 
    }
    function Exports([string] $paramName, $dictionary) 
    { 
        if ($dictionary.Keys.Count -gt 0)
        {
            $keys = $dictionary.Keys -join ",";
            return " -$paramName $keys"
        }
    }
    $fns = Exports "Function" $localModule.ExportedFunctions;
    $aliases = Exports "Alias" $localModule.ExportedAliases;
    $cmdlets = Exports "Cmdlet" $localModule.ExportedCmdlets;
    $vars = Exports "Variable" $localModule.ExportedVariables;
    $exports = "Export-ModuleMember $fns $aliases $cmdlets $vars;";

    $moduleString= @"
if (get-module $moduleName)
{
    remove-module $moduleName;
}
New-Module -name $moduleName {
$($localModule.Definition)
$exports;
}  | import-module
"@
    $script = [ScriptBlock]::Create($moduleString);
    invoke-command -session $session -scriptblock $script;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe this is supported right of the box without any "hacks". The smart move would probably be to put the module on a public location like a fileserver and import it on the server when you need it. Ex:

```
$session = new-pssession -computerName server01
invoke-command -session $session -scriptblock {
    #Set executionpolicy to bypass warnings IN THIS SESSION ONLY
    Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process
    #Import module from public location
    Import-Module \\fileserver\folders\modulelocation...


    <# use function defined in MyCustomModule here #> 
}
```

Comment: The issue with this approach will be then overcoming the double hop problem.

Answer (score 2):

Since PS 5.0, I think there is now another cleaner way:

Utilise Copy-Item's ToSession parameter to copy the local module to the remote machine.

This doesn't involve the disadvantages of previous solutions:

- No need to copy the module to remote machines before hand
- No shared folders or re-creating the module dynamically:

**Example usage:**

```
$s = New-PSSession MyTargetMachine
Get-Module MyLocalModule | Import-LocalModuleToRemoteSession -Session $s -Force
# Show module is loaded
Invoke-Command $s -ScriptBlock { Get-Module }
```

**Import-LocalModuleToRemoteSession function**

*Note it doesn't load the module dependencies*

```
<#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Imports a loaded local module into a remote session
        
    .DESCRIPTION 
        This script copies a module's files loaded on the local machine to a remote session's temporary folder and imports it, before removing the temporary files.
                
        It does not require any shared folders to be exposed as it uses the default Copy-To -ToSession paramter (added in PS 5.0). 
#>
function Import-LocalModuleToRemoteSession
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        # Module to import
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName,Mandatory)]
        [System.Management.Automation.PSModuleInfo]$ModuleInfo,

        # PSSession to import module to
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSession]
        $Session,

        # Override temporary folder location for module to be copied to on remote machine 
        [string]
        $SessionModuleFolder=$null,

        [switch]
        $Force,

        [switch]
        $SkipDeleteModuleAfterImport

    )

    begin{
        function New-TemporaryDirectory {
            $parent = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath()
            [string] $name = [System.Guid]::NewGuid()
            New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path (Join-Path $parent $name)
        }
    }

    process{
        
        if( [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($SessionModuleFolder) ){
            Write-Verbose "Creating temporary module folder"
            $item = Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock ${function:New-TemporaryDirectory} -ErrorAction Stop
            $SessionModuleFolder = $item.FullName
            Write-Verbose "Created temporary folder $SessionModuleFolder"
        }

        $directory = (Join-Path -Path $SessionModuleFolder -ChildPath $ModuleInfo.Name)
        Write-Verbose "Copying module $($ModuleInfo.Name) to remote folder: $directory"
        Copy-Item `
            -ToSession $Session `
            -Recurse `
            -Path $ModuleInfo.ModuleBase `
            -Destination $directory
        
        Write-Verbose "Importing module on remote session @ $directory "

        try{
            Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ErrorAction Stop -ScriptBlock `
            { 
                Get-ChildItem (Join-Path -Path ${Using:directory} -ChildPath "*.psd1") `
                    | ForEach-Object{ 
                        Write-Debug "Importing module $_"
                        Import-Module -Name $_ #-Force:${Using:Force}
                    }
                
                    if( -not ${Using:SkipDeleteModuleAfterImport} ){
                        Write-Debug "Deleting temporary module files: $(${Using:directory})"
                        Remove-Item -Force -Recurse ${Using:directory}
                    }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Write-Error "Failed to import module on $Session with error: $_"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about making scriptblock out of your custom function and sending it off to terget servers using `Invoke-command`

```
Import-module YourModule
$s = [scriptblock]::Create($(get-item Function:\Your-ModuleFunction).Definition)

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $s -Computername s1,s2,sn
```

Comment: Wont work because module can reference its own functions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this thread it was helpfull….

But i actually rewrote the function.

Be aware, that nether the original function in this post or this rewritten function includes module manifest data. So you cant rely on version checks on the module.

```
function Import-ModuleRemotely {
    Param (
        [string] $moduleName,
        [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSession] $session
    )

    Import-Module $moduleName

    $Script = @"
    if (get-module $moduleName)
    {
        remove-module $moduleName;
    }

    New-Module -Name $moduleName { $($(Get-Module $moduleName).Definition) } | Import-Module
"@

    Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {
        Param($Script)
        . ([ScriptBlock]::Create($Script))
        Get-Module 
    } -ArgumentList $Script
}
```