# Can I hide internal helper methods in a Powershell ps1 script?

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

For example, one (bad) idea I had would be to import a module from a string defined in the file (I don't know if I can do this without first writing this string to the file system)

I'm writing a script that I want to be able to execute remotely, and following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14889496/738851) I'm using the "Scripts Approach". However, I want to hide some of the functions somehow - I'd like a sort of module within a script.

Or is there a completely different approach to what I'm trying to do? All my scripts/modules are client side, and I want to run them in a remote PSSession. I don't particularly want to handle copying of scripts to the remote server or shared drive.

I am using the following to dot source my script into a remote PSSession:

```
invoke-command -Session $s -FilePath $p
```

and then invoking a scriptblock making use of the functions defined in the script file `$p`. This works, but I don't think this works with modules, and if I want to reuse code in other scripts, I either have to manually import each one into the remote session, or duplicate code in a single monolithic script. Neither is appealing, and neither seems to allow hiding of "private" methods.

Comment: I think you've painted yourself into a corner.  If all of the script components are going to reside on the local machine, then the user has to be able to read it in order to invoke it.

Comment: @mjolinor - I don't see why that is necessarily the case. E.g. if I have a module file locally that I can read, the non-exported methods in that module file are still "hidden" when I import the module. That is what I mean by "hidden"

Comment: From Get-Help Import-Module: Description
    The Import-Module cmdlet adds one or more modules to the current session. The modules that you import must be installed on the local computer or a remote computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `New-Module` cmdlet:

```powershell
New-Module {
    function a {
        b
    }
    function b {
        'function b called'
    }
    Export-ModuleMember a
}|Out-Null
a #OK
b #Error
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! And piping it to Import-Module lets me remove it later if I should wish