# Not able to use a function from another powershell file

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-remoting

I have the `main.ps1 file` where I am importing another file `$dirpath\new.ps1` as below:

```
Import-module $dirpath\new.ps1 -force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
try {
    $getval = invoke-command -cn $host -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
    param($name)    
    get-myfunc $name
    } -ArgumentList $name
    
} catch { 
    ...
    }
```

Both `main.ps1 file` and `new.ps1` are existing under the same directory - `$dirpath.`

The `new.ps1` looks as below:

```
Function global:get-myfunc{
PARAM(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)][STRING]$name
)
    write-host "$name"

}
```

Now, the `main.ps1 file` is throwing below error:

```
+     $getval = invoke-command -cn $host -Credential $cred -S ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (get-myfunc:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I have tried renaming `new.ps1` as `new.psm1` then importing module as `Import-module $dirpath\new.psm1` but it is still failing with same error.

I am using `poweshell 5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### First issue

The `new.ps1` file isn't a module, just a regular script, so you can't/shouldn't use `Import-Module` for that.

Modules are not simply scripts with a different extension. For more information, see:

- [about Modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_modules?view=powershell-5.1)
- [How to Write a PowerShell Script Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/how-to-write-a-powershell-script-module?view=powershell-5.1)

If you want to keep the current setup, *dot source* the script by replacing the `Import-Module` line with:

```
. $dirpath\new.ps1
```

This will execute the script and make define the function in the current scope.

If the script is located in the same folder as the calling script, you can further simplify the statement by using `$PSScriptRoot`:

```
. $PSScriptRoot\new.ps1
```

##### Second issue

`Invoke-Command` means you're running a scriptblock on a different host, which implies that it uses a different scope. That's why it can't find the `get-myfunc` function.

The modifying your statement to:

```
Invoke-Command 
    -ComputerName $host `
    -Credential $cred `
    -ScriptBlock ${Function:get-myfunc} `
    -ArgumentList $name
```

For a more detailed explanation, see [Run Local Functions Remotely in PowerShell](https://duffney.io/run-local-functions-remotely-in-powershell/).

Comment: I have tried renaming `new.ps1` as `new.psm1` then importing module as `Import-module $dirpath\new.psm1` but it is still failing

Comment: Please read the documentation regarding modules. Modules are not just scripts with a different extension. For functions to be available, you have to export them.

Comment: got it thanks. can you please let me know if it is correct way to export? `Export-ModuleMember -Function get-myfunc`

Comment: I am now using `. $dirpath\new.ps1` but `main.ps1 file` is still failing for same reason.

Comment: I added links to the documentation that describe how to implement modules.

Answer (score 1):

That Won't work, because you are importing that Module into your local machine. But, the below command is executing in remote machine. That means you need install that module in remote machine and then you can use that module in the remote machine.

$getval = invoke-command -cn $host -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
param($name)
get-myfunc $name

Please follow below [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14441800/how-to-import-custom-powershell-module-into-the-remote-session) for the solution